# How to make NTLM request with Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am trying make a service request with NTLM Authentication challenge.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET,
            "http://<theurl>").authenticate(usingCredential: NSURLCredential(user: "<theuser>", password: "<thepwd>", persistence: .ForSession)).response {
                (request, response, data, error )  in
                println(request)
                println(response)
                println(error)
        }
```

But it always give be HTTP 405 error. What's the right way to implement this?

Comment: Hi Sarat, could you found any solution for this?